# Is there a way to group by multiple criteria and then count data?

Tags: excel

```
Pickup Received BUILDING ROOM

7/12/2018         50     0G39
7/12/2018         50     0G39
9/13/2018        101     0275B
9/13/2018        101     0275B
9/13/2018        101     0275B
8/10/2018       1000     206
8/10/2018       1000     206
8/22/2018       1000     208
```

I am looking to count data based off of a group of multiple criteria. I would like to group matching building and rooms with the same date and count them as one. My goal is to determine the number of pickups (where same date, building, and room is one trip).

Example:

```
Pickup Received BUILDING ROOM

7/12/2018       50       0G39
7/12/2018       50       0G39
This is one
9/13/2018       101      0275B
9/13/2018       101      0275B
9/13/2018       101      0275B
This is one
8/10/2018       1000     206
8/10/2018       1000     206
This is one
8/22/2018       1000     208
This is one
```

Is this possible with Excel?

Comment: Looks like a job for a pivot table.

Comment: Maybe an extra column `=CONCATENATE(A1; B1; C1)` then use SUMIF or appropriate formulas? (edit) or pivottable should do the trick.

Comment: sorting and either subtotals or pivot table can do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a pivot table this trick should work. Concatenate key columns then `vlookup+iserror` flag to mark first instance row. You can `SUM()` flag column to have a total number of distinct pickups. You may embed a concat function inside the flag formula if you wish.

```
Pickups
Date Building Room  Concat                           DistinctFlag
.    .        .     =CONCATENATE(A3;",";B3;",";C3)   =1
.    .        .     =CONCATENATE(A4;",";B4;",";C4)   =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D4;$D$3:D3;1; FALSE)); 1; 0)
.    .        .     =CONCATENATE(A5;",";B5;",";C5)   =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D5;$D$3:D4;1; FALSE)); 1; 0)
.    .        .     =CONCATENATE(A6;",";B6;",";C6)   =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D6;$D$3:D5;1; FALSE)); 1; 0)
Total Pickups:      =SUM(E3:E999)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easily with formulas

First formula: `=A1 & B1 & C1` - Just merge the three cells together into D1.

Then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(data,data))
```

Where Data is your D1:D? Range.